# How to find overall data trends from count data across multiple subjects

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, count-data

I'm working with a dataset on ecosystem invasion, where individuals of an invasive species are "colonizing" a specific species of tree, tracked over time. Count data were collected 4-6 times in regular discrete intervals on 23 individual trees, with counts increasing on some trees and decreasing on others week to week. Raw counts vary up to an order of magnitude, e.g.

Tree 1 counts: 5, 8, 12, 12, 15

Tree 2 counts: 25, 70, 115, 110, 100, 130

Tree 3 counts: 140, 300, 450, 378, 295, 280

I'm attempting to describe the invasion with a linear regression/ glm / poisson regression that aggregates all trees together to capture how the the invasion has progressed from the start to end date. I'm assuming I need to modify the data to represent proportional increases/decreases in order to compare a tree with 3 individuals to a tree with 300. Which regression would fit these data best? I attempted to use glmer() in R but quickly got overwhelmed by syntax and lost the plot.

The only other independent factor available is the constant variable tree height, representing available area for invasion, the effect of which I would like to test

Comment: A standard transformation is to take the natural log of the counts before running an OLS regression. However widely used, this approach is not without its problems, see, e.g., here https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4120293/  Along with tree height, you can use IVs for time of measure and species of tree and geographic location, as appropriate.